# Complemented closed subspace isomorphic to $\ell^1$

Tags: functional-analysis

I would like to prove that in $L^1[0,\infty)$ I can find (closed) complemented subspaces isomorphic to $L^1[0,1]$ and $\ell^1$. And indeed, the same happen for $L^1[0,1]$ in $\ell^1$.

I have tried to build the isomorphism using that the projection of the set should be continous, but I cannot finish the argument.

Thank you so much.

Comment: You should add $ signs around TeX commands such as L^1[0,\infty) so that they render properly.